# Update ListIndex partial view from Edit partial view without refreshing the page

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two partial views, one for Edit and one for ListIndex which contains grid to list table data.

I want to get updated ListIndex page, when the "Update" button on the Edit partial view form is clicked.

> Here page doesn't update itself. Only after refreshing the page, it is being updated.

Here is the code for ListIndex view - **LoctionIndex.cshtml**

```
   @MvcHtmlString.Create(
                @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "tablegeneral",
           fillEmptyRows: true,
           mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
           firstText: "<< First",
           previousText: "< Prev",
           nextText: "Next >",
           lastText: "Last >>",
           columns: new[]
           {
               grid.Column("LOC_NAME","BINNO"),
               grid.Column(format: @<text>          @Ajax.EditModalDialogActionLink("Edit","Edit","Location","Edit Location","Model",(long)item.LOC_CODE)</text>),
               grid.Column(format: @<text> @Ajax.EditModalDialogActionLink("Delete", "Delete","Location", "Delete Location","model",(long)item.LOC_CODE)</text>)
           }).ToString().Replace("<tfoot>", "<tfoot> <tr><td colspan=\"7\" align=\"center\">  Records " + firstRecord + " to " + lastRecord + " of " + grid.TotalRowCount + "</tr>"))
```

Here is the code for the user control that's supposed to update:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditModalDialogActionLink(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controller, string dialogTitle, string div, long Locid)
    {
        var dialogDivId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controller, new {id=Locid },
                ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = dialogDivId,
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    OnBegin = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "prepareModalDialog('{0}')", dialogDivId),
                    OnFailure = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "clearModalDialog('{0}');alert('Ajax call failed')", dialogDivId),
                    OnSuccess = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "openModalDialog('{0}', '{1}')", dialogDivId, dialogTitle)
                });
    }
```

And this is my LocationController:

```
public class LocationController : MasterController
{
    private ROCKWELLTESTEntities db = new ROCKWELLTESTEntities();
    //
    // GET: /Master/Location/

    public ActionResult LocationIndex(string text)
    {
        if (TempData["msg"] != null)
        {
            ViewData["error"] = TempData["msg"];
            text = null;
        }
        IEnumerable<location_master> locms;
        if (text == null)
        {
            locms = db.location_master.ToList().Where(l => l.LOC_DEL.Equals(0));
        }
        else
        {
            locms = db.location_master.ToList().Where(l => l.LOC_DEL.Equals(0) && l.LOC_NAME.Contains(text));
        }
        return View(locms);
    }        

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        location_master locms = db.location_master.Find(id);
        return PartialView(locms); 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(location_master locms)
    {
        return editProcessDialog(locms, "Location Updated");
    }

    ActionResult editProcessDialog(location_master locms, string message)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (locms != null)
            {
                db.Entry(locms).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(string.Format("<div data-dialog-close='true' data-dialog-result='{0}'/>", message));
                return PartialView("Edit");                      
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Location Not Exist"));
            }
        }
        return PartialView(locms);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need to refresh the whole table. You already know the values from the form controls, so if the save was successful, just update the cells in the corresponding rows.

Comment: Saving data is successful. But how can update only those cells in the corresponding rows in that page.

Comment: When you click on the 'Edit' link, your can get the associated row using `var cells = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');` Then in the success callback you can update the row cells using `cells.eq(0).text($('#LOC_NAME').val());` etc. And really, you should just include one form in the view (hidden) and when you click on the 'edit' button, do the reverse - i.e. populate the form controls from the existing row values and display it as a dialog. Your current use of the (obsolete) `Ajax.ActionLink()` and `Ajax.BeginForm()` is just degrading performance.